# Get child of dictionary with unknown parent key

Tags: swift, dictionary

I have a dictionary from type [String: Any] that looks like this

```
"arExtensions" : {
        "images" : {
          "-LmgO2yG_TWbfOM4Y8X3" : {
            "imagePath" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/gpk-citycards.appspot.com/o/ARResources%2F78E88F6D-52F0-43A3-B585-9760D19F0B81?alt=media&token=be3a664f-a94b-4ead-bea4-1197155c016e",
            "position" : "bottom"
          },
          "-LmgO4qaMKupHZIAEoLk" : {
            "imagePath" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/gpk-citycards.appspot.com/o/ARResources%2FC7303CF9-0E86-4DC6-A5F5-2761537F0A30?alt=media&token=1f928774-8221-474b-881e-7f395e439131",
            "position" : "rightMiddle"
          },
          "-LmgO9vLT8rEx9Ndog4S" : {
            "imagePath" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/gpk-citycards.appspot.com/o/ARResources%2F9132B5B6-E904-4BCE-B56A-0271CB901A7D?alt=media&token=bd66cd1d-494b-4a82-8d74-6e00ac8c8ae6",
            "position" : "leftMiddle"
          }
        }
      }
```

I want to add the images into an object.

```
var imageObjects: [ImageObject] = []
```

I know that I can get the values with the keys like this

```
let dictImages: [String: Any] = dictArExtensions["images"] as! [String : Any]
```

unfortunately I don't know the key of the children of images.

with two iteration, first to get the key, second to get the needed values i solved the problem like this

```
        var imageKeys: [String] = []
        for dict in dictImages{
            print(dict.key)
            imageKeys.append(dict.key)
            print(dict.value)
        }

        for keys in imageKeys{
            let dictImage: [String: Any] = dictImages[keys] as! [String : Any]
            let imagePath = dictImage["imagePath"] as? String
            let position = dictImage["position"] as? String

            imageObjects.append(ImageObject(imagePath: imagePath!, position: position!))
        }
```

but, it seems like a bad solution.
Is there a better or rather more professional solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enumerate the dictionary very simply with `key` and `value` but the `key` is actually unused.

And if you declare the child dictionary as `[String:String]` you can get rid of the type cast

```
for (_, value) in dictImages {
    let dictImage = value as! [String:String]
    let imagePath = dictImage["imagePath"]
    let position = dictImage["position"]

    imageObjects.append(ImageObject(imagePath: imagePath!, position: position!))
}
```

Please read the section about dictionaries in the [Language Guide](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html#ID113)

Comment: Thanks, I will try this as soon as  I can